# how to make object's array from several array

Tags: javascript, arraylist

For example,

I have a total of two arrangements.

The key array has keys.

The remaining arrays are multi arrays in one array like [[A], [B], [C], ...]

So how do we put objects in one array?

```
let key = [“name”, “age”, “country”];

let values = [["james", "23", "US"],["steve", "20", "UK"], ...]


** expect result **
result = [
    {
        "name": "james",
        "age": 23,
        "country": "US"
    },
    {
        "name": "steve",
        "age": 20,
        "country": "UK"
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: can be done in a array map and inside do a foreach to create the object to return. you can get access to the array indices from foreach and that index can be used to get the value of the key in keys array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single line using array `map` and `reduce` functions:

```
values.map(v=>(key.reduce((acc, k, i) => ({...acc, [k]: v[i]}), {})));
```

(Note your original question contains non-ASCII quotation marks `“”` - you need to use `"` for valid JS syntax).

Answer (score 1):

if you have data as name age and country with same keys so you can try below code it should work for you.

```
let values = [["james", "23", "US"],["steve", "20", "UK"], ...]
const result = [];

values.forEach(item => {
    const [name, age, country] = item;
    result.push({ name, age, country });
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is the cleanest approach with O(n) time

Comment: Yes if you don't mind hard-coding the keys. OP has specifically provided a `key`s array...

Answer (score 0):

I just asked your question to OpenAI JavaScript Codex and it returned this result.

```
/* let key = [“name”, “age”, “country”]; */
var key = ["name", "age", "country"];
/* let values = [["james", "23", "US"],["steve", "20", "UK"]] */
var values = [["james", "23", "US"],["steve", "20", "UK"]];
/* So how do we put objects in one array? */
var objects = [];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  var object = {};
  for (var j = 0; j < key.length; j++) {
    object[key[j]] = values[i][j];
  }
  objects.push(object);
}
```

I really don't know if it works or not, but I am curious to see what it does. You should try this.

Please forgive me if it doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const objs = values.map(
 (valSet) => 
  Object.fromEntries(
   valSet.map(
    (val,i) => [val,keys[i]]
   )
  )
);
```

make entry arrays and then use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)